Cartesian products and 1-element tuples
Sorry if this has been asked before.  The Cartesian products of single-element sets are simple to express:
\begin{eqnarray}
\{(a)\} &\stackrel{?}{=}& \{a\} \tag{1} \\
\{(a, b)\} &=& \{a\} \times \{b\} \tag{2} \\
\{(a, b, c)\} &=& \{a\} \times \{b\} \times \{c\} \tag{3} \\
&\vdots&
\end{eqnarray}
Equations (2) and (3) are non-controversial, regardless of the tuple representation (Kuratowski, or whatever).   Equation (1), however, is odd--it seems unlikely to me that a one-element tuple $(a)$ is equal to its element $a$, even though the semantic content is the same (I think).  Can one-element tuples make sense?  They're certainly not uncommon in computer science.

With the usual set theoretic definition of the ordered pair $(a,b)$ as the set $\{ a,  \{a,b\}\}$ you can define the Cartesian product of two sets and then
inductively define the Cartesian product of $n \ge 2$ sets.
It's not customary in set theory to define the Cartesian product of one set. It might be reasonable and consistent with most usage to define that as the set itself.
You can define that product using category theory .
